# Shift is switching keys when pressed 1 time

Tags: keyboard

When I want to type in uppercase (for example) I hold shift during my typing. However, I notice that Elementary is doing something odd: when I press shift key, even though I release it immediately, it keeps its behavior and type in uppercase for only one character, like I'm holding shift key or typing.

I don't know if it's a bug but I didn't find any settings to change this setting.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution: Settings -> Universal Access -> Keyboard. Option "Use Modifiers Keys in Sequence (Sticky Keys)" was activated. Disable it and Shift key went normal again.[image: Settings]